# Validations codes are not working properly in the grid view

Tags: vb.net, gridview

i am working on vb.net windows application..i have a grid view like this:[image]

in save button first i want to do some validation..

if the company name is there,,then i should enter all other fields(department,phoen,mail)

if i have only company name and i click save button,,then it should show message box .
so i given code something like this

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To gv.RowCount - 2
            If gv.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString.Length <> 0 Then

                 If gv.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value Is Nothing AndAlso IsDBNull(gv.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value) Then
                    MsgBox("Please Enter Department Details")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

in this case if department column not having any value then also not showing message box under if condition..what is wrong with my code

Comment: is `gv.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value` mean the company column ??

Comment: yes sir,,if the company column have some value then only i want to check department column have the value or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the company column in position `Zero` So you need to edit your code like this :

```
For i As Integer = 0 To gv.RowCount - 2
        If gv.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString.Length <> 0 AndAlso Not IsDBNull(gv.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value  Then

             If gv.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString.Length = 0 OrElse IsDBNull(gv.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value) Then
                MsgBox("Please Enter Department Details")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
Next
```

Comment: sir i am hiding first column ,my company in position 1 only

Comment: sir problem with this line of code: If gv.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value Is Nothing AndAlso IsDBNull(gv.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value) Then..if i not given any value to department column  then also not showing any message